# Test scores have mean $7.4$ and variance $1.2$. The teacher is in charge of two courses of $40$ students each.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem

Approximate the probability that the average grade of class A exceeds the average grade of class B by more than $0.5$ points.

*Hint:* Consider what needs to happen with the sum of the grades for each course.

**Solution:**

By the Central Limit Theorem: Let $X_1 , X_2 , \ldots$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables, each having mean $7.4$ and variance $1.2$. Then,

$\frac{\sqrt{n} \ (\bar{X} - 7.4)}{\sqrt{1,2}} \rightarrow^{d} N(0,1)$

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be the students of class A.

Let $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots$ be the students of class B.

I think I need to calculate:

$P\big(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{40} X_i}{40} - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{40} Y_i}{40} > 0.5\big) $

but I don't know how to proceed. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are given a population mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, with each student's grade (across all classes) independently and identically distributed according to this population. Let's denote a generic student's grade from class $A$ or class $B$ by $X_i$ or $Y_i$ respectively.  There are $n$ students in each class.

You want to compute $$P\left({1 \over n}\sum_i X_i  -{1 \over n}\sum_i Y_i>0.5      \right)=P\left({1 \over n}\sum_i X_i - Y_i>0.5      \right).$$

Note $E[X_i-Y_i]=0,\text{Var}(X_i-Y_i)=2\sigma^2$ so CLT tells us that

$$\sqrt n\left({1 \over n}\sum_i X_i - Y_i\right)\rightarrow^{d}N(0,2\sigma^2),$$

so we obtain the following approximation:

$$\begin{align}
P\left({1 \over n}\sum_i X_i - Y_i>0.5 \right)&=P\left(\sqrt{{n \over 2\sigma^2}}\left({1 \over n}\sum_i X_i - Y_i\right)>0.5\sqrt{{n \over 2\sigma^2}} \right)\\
&=1-P\left(\sqrt{{n \over 2\sigma^2}}\left({1 \over n}\sum_i X_i - Y_i\right)\leq 0.5\sqrt{{n \over 2\sigma^2}} \right)\\
&\approx 1-\Phi\left(0.5\sqrt{{n \over 2\sigma^2}}\right)
\end{align}$$

where $\Phi$ is the CDF of a standard normal.